# Why can an affirmative conclusion never be drawn from negative premises?

Tags: logic, syllogism

<sub>Source: *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014), by Patrick J. Hurley.

Please observe my amelioration (and so change) of Hurley's notation.</sub>

> [p 287:] Rule 4: A Negative Premise Requires a Negative Conclusion, [...]
>   Fallacy: Drawing an affirmative conclusion from a negative premise [...]
>
> [p 288:] [...] The logic behind Rule 4 may be seen as follows. If MIN, MAJ, and MID once again designate
>   the Minor, Major, and Middle Terms, an affirmative conclusion always states that the
>   MIN class is contained either wholly or partially in the MAJ class.
>
> The only way that such
>   a conclusion can follow is if the MIN  class is contained either wholly or partially in the
>   MID class,
>
> [1.] and the MID class **wholly** in the MAJ class.
>
> In other words, it follows only when both
>   premises are affirmative. But if, for example, the MIN class is contained either wholly or
>   partially in the MID class, and the MID class is separate either wholly or partially from the
>   MAJ class, such a conclusion will never follow. Thus, an affirmative conclusion cannot be
>   drawn from negative premises.

I pursue only intuition; please do not answer with formal proofs or Truth Tables.

The argument above does not convince me, because why must 1 be true (ie: why must the MID be contained wholly in MAJ)? An affirmative conclusion can follow even if the MID is contained partially in MAJ.

For example, consider an III syllogism <sup>♦</sup>which is invalid:
Some A are B. Some B are C. → Some A are C.
However, this becomes valid if at least one element lies in A ∩ B ∩ C.

> <sup>♦</sup>[p 288:] As a result of the interaction of these first four rules, it turns out that no valid syllogism
>   can have two particular premises.

Answer (score 1):

*Comment*

*Valid* means true in **all** cases.

Thus, the schema :

> Some A are B
>
> Some B are C
>
> > Therefore : Some A are C

is **not** valid exactly for the reason you have stated :

> it becomes **true** [not valid] if at least one element lies in A ∩ B ∩ C.

Correct..., but if this is not, the argument does not conclude, and this means that the argument form is not valid.

---

This distinction between *true* and *valid* is the core of Hurley's explanation of **Rule 4** (and is the core of *formal logic*, since Aristotle).

Consider the fallacy :

> Drawing an affirmative conclusion from a negative premise,

and consider the *invalid* :

> All crows are birds
>
> Some wolves are not crows
>
> > Therefore : Some wolves are birds.

This is a counter-example to the "purported" rule :

> it is possible to (validly) conclude in the affermative when a premise is negative.

This means that, from the fact :

> if a schema has one premise negative and the conclusion affermative, then it is **not** valid,

by contraposition we have :

> if a schema is valid, then **not** (one premise negative and the conclusion affermative) i.e. either the conclusion is negative or all the premise must be afermative.